# K.l2_normalize wont normalize latent vector to length 1, but ~0.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I try to normalize the output of my encoder to length one. I use the plaidml backend.

```
def backend_l2_normalize(tensor):
    return K.l2_normalize(tensor,axis=None)
norm = Lambda(backend_l2_normalize,name = "backend_normalize")
```

I also tried setting axis to [-1,0,1] but all values other than None produce 'nan' values in the latent vector. As far as I understand, the function gets single tensors. So I think axis=0 should be correct.

With this setup I get normalized vectors but with length e.g. 0.17167852226827016. And the length is changing while training. I use :

`print("Example input vector norm: ",np.linalg.norm(feature_vektors[0]))`

to print the norm in a callback. I also tried re-implementing the norm with the backend functions:

```
def custom_l2_normalize(tensor):
    norm = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(tensor),axis=None,keepdims=False))
    return tensor / norm
```

Exactly the same outcome. Why is this happening? Am I missing something here?

Here is my autoencoder:
-- EDIT --

```
    enc = Sequential()

    downsamp1 = Conv2D(32, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='relu',
                     kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k), bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                     kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer)

    downsamp2 = Conv2D(16, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='relu',
                     kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k), bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                     kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer)

    downsamp3 = Conv2D(settings.ENCODER_OUTPUT_KERNELS, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                     activation='relu', bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k), kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                     kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer)

    flatten = Flatten()

    norm = Lambda(backend_l2_normalize, name="backend_normalize")
    # norm = Lambda(custom_l2_normalize, name="custom_normalize")


    upsamp1 = Deconv2D(settings.ENCODER_OUTPUT_KERNELS, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                       activation='relu',
                       kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer, kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                       bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k))
    upsamp2 = Deconv2D(16, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                       activation='relu', kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer, kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                       bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k))

    upsamp3 = Deconv2D(3, settings.KERNEL_SIZE, padding='same', strides=(2, 2),
                       activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=conv2d_initializer, kernel_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k),
                       bias_regularizer=l2(regulizer_k))
 reshape = Reshape(target_shape=(
        4, 4, settings.ENCODER_OUTPUT_KERNELS),
        input_shape=(settings.ENCODER_OUTPUT_SIZE,))




    enc.add(downsamp1)
    enc.add(downsamp2)
    enc.add(downsamp3)
    enc.add(flatten)

    #I compute the norm in the layer while training.
    enc.add(norm)

    input1 = Input(shape=(settings.SQUARE_LENGTH, settings.SQUARE_LENGTH, 3))

    auto = enc(input1)

    auto = reshape(auto)
    auto = upsamp1(auto)
    auto = upsamp2(auto)
    auto = upsamp3(auto)

    auto_model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=auto)
    auto_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(settings.AUTO_LEARNING_RATE),
                       metrics=['acc'])
```

I test the length of the vectors with a callback:

```
class FisherLogger(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self,test_data):
        self.test_data = test_data

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        model = self.model
        encoder = models.get_encoder(model)
        pred = model.predict(self.test_data)
        print(np.linalg.norm(pred[0]))
```

This is a simplification. I actually test more than one vector and also compute the norm of the mean of the whole dataset.

Comment: You will either have to provide more code (where are you computing the L2-norm of the vectors?) Or you will have to provide some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `l2_normalize` means that your vector is 1 when taking the L2 norm (for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html)). You are checking the length with L1 norm. If you want your vector to be of length 1 you need to normalize w.r.t. the L1 norm.

e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1.,2.3,3.1])
a = tf.keras.backend.l2_normalize(a)
print(tf.norm(a, 2))
>>>tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Am I? I use np.linalg.norm(). It says it calculates l2/frobenius norm for ord=None. I also tried `np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(vektor)))` which returns the same value.